# ExceptionInInitializerError - using getResourceAsStream to read a file in a jar package

Tags: java, jar, java-io

I'm trying to read a file (blip3.out) that will be in a jar package. I am using getResourceAsStream to get the url and and then try to read from it. I've made multiple attempts, with solutions from other posts, but I am still getting an **ExceptionInInitializerError**. Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong or what the issue might be.

Also, from what I understand if I can get the get resource stream working then it should include the blip3.out file to the jar package. Is this correct?

**Code:**

```
public Set<String> readWindowTitleSet() {
    try {
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("blip3.out");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        anotherList = (HashSet<String>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return anotherList;

}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at view.MainGui.<init>(MainGui.java:29)
at view.MainGui.main(MainGui.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at model.WindowTitleDataStore.readWindowTitleSet(WindowTitleDataStore.java:47)
at model.WindowTitleDataStore.<init>(WindowTitleDataStore.java:18)
at controller.InterruptionDecision.<clinit>(InterruptionDecision.java:23)
... 2 more
```

Comment: Well it sounds like `blip3.out` isn't available at execution time. Yes, adding it to the jar file should sort it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the error is simple: you actually pass `null` as an inputstream (looking at the sources of `PeekInputStream#read` shows that there's no other reason for that). Add a null check and move the file to the correct location, because the application can't find it there at runtime.

*(Guessing not knowing: place it in the "view" folder in your sources directory)*